# how to store selected value in devextreme headerfilter in jquery variable

Tags: jquery, devexpress, devextreme

i am using devextreme datagrid i am new to devextreme

how to store selected value in devextreme headerfilter in jquery variable on click of button **ok**

example in below image selected value **Pending at PG** store in jquery variable on click of button **ok**

any help will be greatly appreciated

[image]